# Map parameter to function

Tags: python

I have this function, which checks the value of myparam and maps it to a function depending on the value. Myfunction1 and Myfunction3 just use the param1 passed to the foo function, but myfunction2 will need the param2 as well.

```
def foo(myparam, param1, param2=None):
    if myparam == 1:
        return myfunction1(param2)
    if myparam == 2:
        return myfunction2(param1, param2)
    if myparam == 3:
        return myfunction3(param1)
```

How could I convert this to functional programming and thus avoid the harcoded mapping?

Comment: Avoiding the use of dictionaries? Is a match statement with an if-statement before OK?

Comment: You seem to have working code here. Does it work for you? The only issue is with `myparam`. What happens if it is not one of the approved values? Anyhow you could replace the last two `if`s with `elif`.

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO I am open to any ideas, yes.

Comment: What speaks against the idea of just calling the functions directly, without having an intermediate `foo` method? In what situations do you call these functions and where do you get `myparam` from?

Comment: Since calling `foo` requires to select the target function and provide all arguments to it, why not call the target function directly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're *aiming for* here, but if you want a possible implementation...

You could use `inspect.signature()` to figure out which parameters are accepted by the target callable and calls them by kwarg.

This implementation would be easier if `foo` accepted `**kwargs` (because you wouldn't need the `args` mapping).

```
import inspect


def myfunction1(param1):
    print("1", locals())


def myfunction2(param1, param2):
    print("2", locals())


def myfunction3(param1):
    print("3", locals())


param_to_fun = {
    1: myfunction1,
    2: myfunction2,
    3: myfunction3,
}


def foo(myparam, param1, param2=None):
    func = param_to_fun[myparam]
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    args = {
        "param1": param1,
        "param2": param2,
    }
    return func(
        **{
            k: v
            for k, v in args.items()
            if k in sig.parameters
        }
    )


foo(1, "a")
foo(2, "a", "b")
foo(3, "c")
foo(2, "d")
```

This outputs

```
1 {'param1': 'a'}
2 {'param1': 'a', 'param2': 'b'}
3 {'param1': 'c'}
2 {'param1': 'd', 'param2': None}
```